# Spring Boot @Autowire not working. Error creating bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired

Hi I have a spring boot project. The main class package is like this :

```
com.som.demo
```

I have used an external jar as a maven dependency in my project. In that jar there is a service class annotated with @Service as below :

```
@Service
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {
      @Autowired
      private TreeCacheWrapper ffCoreCache;

      @Autowired(required = false)
      private ZookeeperProperties zookeeperProperties;

      public SomeServiceImpl(TreeCacheWrapper ffCoreCache, ZookeeperProperties zookeeperProperties) {
         this.ffCoreCache = ffCoreCache;
         this.zookeeperProperties = zookeeperProperties;
      }
}
```

And the main package where this `SomeServiceImpl`  class is as below :

```
com.som.test
```

Now in my project when I am autowiring the class I get the bean creation error while running the spring boot app. This is how I am doing :

```
@Autowired
private SomeService someService;
```

**Error** :

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'someServiceImpl'
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'ffCoreCache'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'ffCoreCache' defined in class path resource [com/som/test/config/ZooKeeperConfig.class]: 
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [com.som.test.cache.TreeCacheWrapper]: 
Factory method 'ffCoreCache' threw exception; 
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/curator/retry/ExponentialBackoffRetry


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'ffCoreCache' defined in class path resource [com/som/test/config/ZooKeeperConfig.class]: 
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [com.som.test.cache.TreeCacheWrapper]: 
Factory method 'ffCoreCache' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/curator/retry/ExponentialBackoffRetry



Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.som.test.cache.TreeCacheWrapper]: 
Factory method 'ffCoreCache' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/curator/retry/ExponentialBackoffRetry

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/curator/retry/ExponentialBackoffRetry

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.curator.retry.ExponentialBackoffRetry
```

Comment: You are getting ClassNotFoundException, you have to add the dependency to the project.

Answer (score 1):

When spring boot application starts, it scans for beans in the same package as your main class, and all packages beneath it.

Since your main class resides in the package `com.som.demo` spring boot will find any beans in this package, or in packages like `com.som.demo.sample1`, `com.som.demo.a.b.c` etc
However it won't scan `com.som.test` package because its a "peer" to the main package.

In general you can configure spring boot to scan the packages of your choice with the help of `@ComponentScan` annotation that accepts a list of base packages to scan. You can put this annotation right on your main class (next to `@SpringBootApplication`).

However this is kind of against the conventions of spring boot.

Read [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning) for more technical details and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate Service **interface** with @Service, not the Implementation class and try to annotate ServiceImplementation class with @Component.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot by default scan to beans in your main package. you can configure it using

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.som.demo" , "com.som.test"})
```